# How do I make the knife tool snap to the locations of vertices without it restarting the process?

Tags: vertices, faces, knife-tool

As seen here I'm trying to make a face cut on a face based on the shape of some edges, but whenever I got from one vertex to another it resets the process removing my previous line point: https://streamable.com/3zssol

Note: I'm aware there are better methods for cutting something with as simple of a shape as this, this is merely an example and there's much more complicated shapes and operations I'm intending do this for.[image]

Comment: you simply can't cut and edge in half in its length. It's just not possible since an edge don't have any thickness